# Yup Validation with addMethod not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup, hook-form

I have the following problem. Been trying for hours solving it, but no chance.
I have updated React vom 17 to 18 recently, as well as all deps.

I have a `validations.ts` file that is called in the main `App.tsx`

Following code is part of the `validations.ts`:

```
yup.addMethod(yup.object, 'birthdate', function () {
    return this.test(
        'birthdate',
        i18n.t('validations:separated_date'),
        (value) => {
            if (value.year < 1900) return false;

            const date = `${value.day}/${value.month}/${value.year}`;
            const today = moment();
            const momentDate = moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);

            return today.isAfter(momentDate);
        },
    );
});
```

On the page I am using the form from `react-hook-form`, I am using following:

```
const form = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(
            yup.object({
                birthdate: yup
                    .object({
                        year: yup.string().required(),
                        month: yup.string().required(),
                        day: yup.string().required(),
                    })
                    .birthdate()
                    .separatedDate(),
                legalGuardianEmail: yup.string().when('birthdate', {
                    is: (birthdateNow: SeparatedDate) => {
                        const hasLegalAge = checkIfOlderThan(
                            birthdateNow,
                            USER_LEGAL_AGE,
                        );
                        return birthdateNow.day && !hasLegalAge;
                    },
                    otherwise: yup.string().transform(() => ''),
                    then: yup
                        .string()
                        .trim()
                        .lowercase()
                        .email()
                        .notOneOf([formValues.email], 'validations:same_email')
                        .required()
                        .validEmail(),
                }),
            }),
        ),
        defaultValues: formValues,
    });
```

I am facing two issues here:

A. the `.birthdate()` is throwing following error:

`Property 'birthdate' does not exist on type 'ObjectSchema<{ year: string; month: string; day: string; }, AnyObject, { year: undefined; month: undefined; day: undefined; }, "">'.ts(2339)`

B. in the section legalGuardianEmail the `is`throws that one:

`No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 4, '(keys: string | string[], builder: ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>): StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">', gave the following error. Argument of type '{ is: (birthdateNow: SeparatedDate) => boolean | ""; otherwise: yup.StringSchema<string | undefined, yup.AnyObject, undefined, "">; then: yup.StringSchema<string | undefined, yup.AnyObject, undefined, "">; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'is' does not exist in type 'ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.ts(2769)`

**Anyone has a clue here?**

This is (partly) my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        ....    
        "i18next": "^23.4.1",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
        "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.1",,
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
        "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
        "yup": "^1.2.0"
        ....
},
"devDependencies": {
        ....
        "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/yup": "^0.29.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.1",
        "eslint": "^8.46.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6"
        ....
}
```

Help would be so much appreciated!

Best
A

Tried a lot, live system is working with that code. I think it is caused by upgrading the deps

Answer (score 0):

try to import `yup` from the `validations.ts` (and export yup from here).

Comment: unfortunately not working either...